# error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: master is initialzing

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have following error while i m trying to create a table in hbase.

> create 'ed', 'edss'
>
> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing

my configuration file is ,

```
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>file:///home/bingo/hbase</value>
```

```
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>/home/bingo/zookeeper</value>
```

and i have set 127.0.0.1 to bingo in my /etc/hosts file..

is this correct does i need to change anything else??

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Please check logs stored in $HBASE_HOME/logs directory.
You will find the reason.
According to my experience it is most probably due to zookeeper connection failure.
If so then change your zookeeper port number.
You can edit that information in $HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml as

`<property> 
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
</property>`